# Error on using xarray open_mfdataset function

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I am trying to combine multiple netCDF files with the same dimensions, their dimensions are as follows:

```
OrderedDict([(u'lat', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lat', size = 720
), (u'lon', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lon', size = 1440
), (u'time', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'time', size = 96
), (u'nv', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'nv', size = 2
)])
OrderedDict([(u'lat', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lat', size = 720
), (u'lon', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lon', size = 1440
), (u'time', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'time', size = 96
), (u'nv', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'nv', size = 2
)])
OrderedDict([(u'lat', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lat', size = 720
), (u'lon', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lon', size = 1440
), (u'time', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'time', size = 96
), (u'nv', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'nv', size = 2
)])
OrderedDict([(u'lat', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lat', size = 720
), (u'lon', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lon', size = 1440
), (u'time', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'time', size = 96
), (u'nv', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'nv', size = 2
)])
OrderedDict([(u'lat', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lat', size = 720
), (u'lon', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lon', size = 1440
), (u'time', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'time', size = 96
), (u'nv', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'nv', size = 2
)])
OrderedDict([(u'lat', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lat', size = 720
), (u'lon', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lon', size = 1440
), (u'time', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'time', size = 96
), (u'nv', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'nv', size = 2
)])
OrderedDict([(u'lat', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lat', size = 720
), (u'lon', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'lon', size = 1440
), (u'time', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'time', size = 96
), (u'nv', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'nv', size = 2
)])
```

However, on using open_mfdataset, I get this error:

```
xr.open_mfdataset(path_file, decode_times=False)

*** ValueError: cannot infer dimension to concatenate: supply the ``concat_dim`` argument explicitly
```

How to fix this error? My dimensions are the same in all the files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message is probably arising because you have two files with the same variables and coordinate values, and xarray doesn't know whether it should stack them together along a new dimension or simply check to make sure none of the values conflict.

It would be nice if explicitly calling `open_mfdataset` with `concat_dim=None` disabled all attempts at concatenation. [This change](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/1007) should make it into the next release of xarray (v0.9.0).

In the meantime, you can work around this by opening the files individually and merging them explicitly, e.g.,

```
def open_mfdataset_merge_only(paths, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(paths, basestring):
        paths = sorted(glob(paths))
    return xr.merge([xr.open_dataset(path, **kwargs) for path in paths])
```

Under the covers, this is basically all that `open_mfdataset` is doing.

Comment: thanks @Stephan, will use this. looking forward to v0.9!

Answer (score 1):

http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html

```
xarray.open_mfdataset(paths, chunks=None, concat_dim=None, preprocess=None, engine=None, lock=None, **kwargs)
```

It looks like it needs you to give a `concat_dim` parameter.  It's having problems inferring it from your data.

> Dimension to concatenate files along. This argument is passed on to xarray.auto_combine() along with the dataset objects. You only need to provide this argument if the dimension along which you want to concatenate is not a dimension in the original datasets, e.g., if you want to stack a collection of 2D arrays along a third dimension.

Are these 3d arrays that you want to stack along a new, 4th, dimension?

Comment: thanks @hpaulj, I am not sure why it is having a problem. also not sure of format needed for concat_dim. Documentation says it should be string or dataarray, but I have 4 dimensions: lat, loon, time, nv

Comment: these netCDF files have exactly the same dimensions, but different variables. I want the output netCDF file to contain all the different variables and of course the dimensions