# concat Datasets along multiple dimensions

Tags: python-xarray

I have multiple data with the same `coords` and similar values for them. I.e., there is no single unique ID but rather a combined ID of `(index, split)`. Ideally, I would just want to append all the datasets one after another, but I haven't found the right way to do so.

```
import xarray as xr
from xarray import Dataset
import numpy as np

datasets = []
for split in range(3):
    dim2_len = 4
    dim1_len = 3
    data_len = 5
    d = Dataset({'data1': (['index', 'dim1'], np.random.rand(data_len, dim1_len)),
                 'data2': (['index', 'dim2'], np.random.rand(data_len, dim2_len)),
                 'data3': (['index', 'dim2'], np.random.rand(data_len, dim2_len))},
                coords={'index': range(data_len),
                        'dim2': range(dim2_len),
                        'dim1': range(dim1_len),
                        'split': split})
    datasets.append(d)

xr.auto_combine(datasets)
# ValueError: too many different dimensions to concatenate: {'dim1', 'dim2', 'index'}
```

The current `xr.concat` / `xr.auto_combine` function does not allow you to concatenate datasets along multiple dimensions (https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/4b8339b53f1b9dcd79f2a9060933713328a13b90/xarray/core/combine.py#L358).
I guess, I could manually take all the data and coords and throw them into a new dataset but it seems like there should be a better way in the library.

Is there a way to concatenate datasets along multiple dimensions?

Comment: Can you provide some code explaining what you've tried and a summary of how your datasets are structured? This question is not complete in its current form.

Comment: I just answered a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545138/python-xarray-open-mfdataset-concat-along-two-dimensions, can you try breaking your `concat` operations into pieces, one dimension at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Xarray does now have this feature - you can use [`combine_nested`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.combine_nested.html#xarray.combine_nested) or [`combine_by_coords`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.combine_by_coords.html) to concatenate along an arbitrary number of dimensions. You can also use either of these algorithms from within [`open_mfdataset`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html). The various functions for combining datasets are covered in the [documentation page here](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/combining.html).