# Concatenate xarray DataArrays simultaneously along 2 dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have a large 2D domain that is broken up into equally-sized 2D patches in several xarray DataArrays. So, for example, a simulation of what I have would be:

```
a=xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(4,4)+0, dims=("x", "y"), coords=dict(x=range(4), y=range(4)))
b=xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(4,4)+1, dims=("x", "y"), coords=dict(x=range(4,8), y=range(4)))
c=xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(4,4)+2, dims=("x", "y"), coords=dict(x=range(4,8), y=range(4,8)))
```

I am trying to put all these patches together to recreate the domain. So in the example case above, if I were to concatenate everything, I would have an 8 by 8 matrix at the end (with one of the "patches" as `np.nan`) and the other three patches corresponding to their respective DataArrays.

I've been trying to automatize this with xarray but so far I've had no success. My closest attempt is using `xr.concat`:

```
d=xr.concat([a,b,c], dim="x")
d.plot.imshow(x="x")
```

This produces the following image, which is obviously wrong:
[image]

Note that in my case the patches are all scrambled, so I can't really rely on a specific order to concatenate. Here, for example, I could do `d=xr.concat([xr.concat([a,b], dim="x"), c], dim="y")`, but only because I know the order.

PS: This may be somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556078/concat-datasets-along-multiple-dimensions), although it's not clear to me what this question actually asks.

Comment: `numpy` doesn't do this kind of thing. Concatenate always works along just one dimension.  There is a relatively new `block` that takes a nested list of arrays, but it ends up calling `concatenate` recursively, one dimension after another.

Comment: @hpaulj `block` seems interesting. I wouldn't mind calling `concatenate` recursively, the problem is that I can't think of a good way to figure out the order in which to call them if I know nothing about the patches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found our you can do this with sequential applications of `combine_first`. It's not ideal, since I have to iterative apply it given a huge list of `DataArray`s, but it's good enough:

```
d=a.combine_first(c).combine_first(b)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
d = xr.combine_by_coords([a,b,c])
```